# Why Closed Area of Vector is conserved when Divergence of velocity vector is zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I had a line from some lectures saying that when div(v)=0, the area of the closed loop by the vector v is conserved on time.
I really can't prove this or find the proof in online.
Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divergence is just a property of $v$.

Your statement however is a restriction of a possible surface $S$ / integration curve $C = \partial S$: $\lVert \dot{S}\rVert = 0$.

E.g. both theorems of Kelvin-Stokes and Gauss allow you to choose your surface of integration freely.

So there must be additional conditions which lead to a restriction on $S$.